# How do we format the logs in the SAM CLI log command to just show the message?

Tags: aws-sam-cli

The SAM CLI function to tail the logs is AWESOME. However, I find the formatting to be too verbose most of the time. The default formatting looks like this:

```
2021/12/13/[$LATEST]c87a125640ed4c66907f22c1d83ca63e 2021-12-13T13:11:09.388000 2021-12-13T13:11:09.388Z    1f99a541-76d7-494f-8f07-3f3e8397eedf    INFO    small change
```

but I want to have the option to just print out the message without the log stream and timestamp information so it just looks like this:

```
INFO    small change
```

Is there a way to pass in a formatting string for the log statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to only print the 5th and 6th column.

Try:

```sh
sam logs -n MyLambdaFunction --tail | awk '{print $5 " " $6}';
```

---

Demo:

```sh
output="2021/12/13/[$LATEST]c87a125640ed4c66907f22c1d83ca63e 2021-12-13T13:11:09.388000 2021-12-13T13:11:09.388Z    1f99a541-76d7-494f-8f07-3f3e8397eedf    INFO    small change";
echo $output | awk '{print $5 " " $6}';
```

Output:

```sh
INFO small
```